# How to test showDialog content in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-hooks

is there a way to test the content within a show dialog?
I am trying to do BDD in the project, The following is the scenario:

`As a User, I would like to add a photo or select one from the gallery so that I can use it on the item.`

The following is the code I am using to test it but for some reason, the test fails.

**add_item_view.dart**

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:my_app_mobile/models/graded_item/graded_item.dart';
import 'package:my_app_mobile/template/index.dart' as template;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class AddItemView extends HookWidget {
  final GradedItem gradedItem;
  static final Key photoKey = Key('#photoKey');
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final void Function() onPhoto;
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  AddItemView({
    @required this.gradedItem,
    this.onPhoto,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _image = useState<File>();

    Future getImage() async {
      final pickedFile = await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image.value = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (onPhoto != null) {
                    onPhoto();
                  }
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(.2),
                    builder: (context) {
                      return CameraOptions();
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  key: photoKey,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add_a_photo,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    size: 44.0,
                  ),
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: template.colors.grey340,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CameraOptions extends StatelessWidget {
  static final Key captureButtonPhotoKey = Key('#captureButtonPhotoKey');
  static final Key chooseButtonPhotoKey = Key('#chooseButtonPhotoKey');
  static final Key cancelButtonKey = Key('#cancelButtonKey');

  final void Function() onCapture;
  final void Function() onChoose;
  final void Function() onCancel;

  CameraOptions({this.onCapture, this.onChoose, this.onCancel});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 200.0,
        width: 200.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**add_item_view_test.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'my_app_mobile/models/graded_item/graded_item.dart';
import 'my_app_mobile/views/dashboard/children/collection/children/add_item/add_item.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

void main() {
  Widget mountApp({GradedItem gradedItem, void Function() onPhoto}) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AddItemView(
        gradedItem: gradedItem,
        onPhoto: onPhoto,
      ),
    );
  }

  testWidgets('should build with no problems', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(mountApp(gradedItem: GradedItem.generate()));
    expect(find.byType(AddItemView), findsOneWidget);
  });

  group('photo', () {
    testWidgets(
      'should photo widget be available',
      (tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(mountApp(
          gradedItem: GradedItem.generate(),
        ));
        expect(find.byKey(AddItemView.photoKey), findsOneWidget);
      },
    );
    testWidgets(
      'should be able to call onPhoto handler when is available',
      (tester) async {
        final fn = MockedFunctions();

        await tester.pumpWidget(mountApp(
          gradedItem: GradedItem.generate(),
          onPhoto: fn.onPhoto,
        ));
        expect(find.byKey(AddItemView.photoKey), findsOneWidget);

        await tester.tap(find.byKey(AddItemView.photoKey));
        verify(fn.onPhoto()).called(1);
      },
    );
    testWidgets(
      'should onPhoto handler open camera options',
      (tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(
          MaterialApp(
            home: Material(
              child: Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AddItemView(
                    gradedItem: GradedItem.generate(),
                    // onPhoto: fn.onPhoto,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

        await tester.tap(find.byKey(AddItemView.photoKey));
        await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        expect(find.byIcon(Icons.camera), findsOneWidget);
      },
    );
  });
}

class MockedFunctions extends Mock {
  void onPhoto();
}
```

Is there a way to do testing on a showDialog function?

Comment: I'm glad that is working now

Comment: No mention of showDialog in code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, for some reason, the code I posted is working, I restarted my computer and now they are working.

Comment: I'm glad that is working now